# Resolving Permissions Problems for WordPress on IIS7

Tags: wordpress, iis-7

I am running WordPress on Win2k8/IIS7 (using httpcache, fastCgi & UrlRewriter 2.0) installed via WPI.  Everything seems to be working fine (uploads, posting via Live Writer, comments, plugins, pretty URLs).

I am trying to update WordPress to the latest version, but I get an error like this:

> Download failed. Destination directory for file streaming does not
>   exist or is not writable

This is the same error that I get when trying to download a theme or update a plugin.

There are no errors in the event log and WordPress isn't really telling me which directory it's looking for, what user it thinks it's using or what permission it is lacking.

I have double (and triple) checked that the IIS App Pool user is explicitly set, and that the directory has modify permissions for that user, and finally that those permissions have been propogated down to sub folders.

At the advice of Dr. Google, I have also added the following settings to the config file:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/');
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Am I missing a config option or a setting?  Does WordPress require the sacrifice of a small kitten and/or an Algerian degu?

Comment: What do you see when you turn on failed request tracing?

Comment: I hadn't turned it on - thanks for the reminder! - but just did and tried to update.  Again, same error in WP, and nothing logged in my log dir.

Comment: Do you resolve your issue?, I have similar problem with wordpress in azure portal, I don't know how to set property file permission for wordpress site

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [PHP manual on IIS7 installation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) (emphasis mine):

> Impersonation and file system access
>
> It is recommended to enable FastCGI impersonation in PHP when using
>   IIS. **This is controlled by *the fastcgi.impersonate directive in
>   php.ini file*. When impersonation is enabled, PHP will perform all the
>   file system operations on behalf of the user account that has been
>   determined by *IIS authentication*.** This ensures that even if the same
>   PHP process is shared across different IIS web sites, the PHP scripts
>   in those web sites will not be able to access each other's files as
>   long as different user accounts are used for IIS authentication on
>   each web site.
>
> For example IIS 7, in its default configuration, has anonymous
>   authentication enabled with built-in user account IUSR used as a
>   default identity. **This means that in order for IIS to execute PHP
>   scripts, it is necessary to grant IUSR account read permission on
>   those scripts.** If PHP applications need to perform write operations on
>   certain files or write files into some folders then IUSR account
>   should have write permission to those.

As discussed in the ["Should I impersonate PHP via FastCGI?" question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/282806/should-i-impersonate-php-via-fastcgi), there are security concerns if you would grant the anonymous user write access rights on your server. For instance, if you have also enabled the WebDAV module, anyone could write to your directories using this protocol!

Therefore my recommendations are:

1. Ensure all your sites have their own *unique Application Pool* assigned.
2. In the *Advanced Settings* under *Processing Model* for the application pool, set the built-in account as `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.
3. Disable impersonation in *php.ini* with `fastcgi.impersonate = 0`, so PHP runs under the *Application Pool Identity* as set in IIS.
4. Set read/write permissions on your folders using the [*automatically generated application pool user account*](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) (e.g. "IIS AppPool\MyAppPoolName").

This way, all PHP scripts are ensured to run under a system account, tied to the Application Pool of the site (isolating it from other sites), and cannot accidentally get too public access via impersonation.

Comment: IIS.net recommends fastcgi.impersonate = 0, are you sure this is correct? http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis

Comment: My guess why ISS website recommends impersonation is because it is needed for Integrated Windows Authentication (intranet sites). Also, the standard web directories have already the correct permissions setup (IUSR* account for anonymous access), making it easier to deploy. I personally feel more comfortable to know which permissions I've assigned to a directory (system account), rather than dynamic impersonation (user account).

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe the following configuration provides the same benefits, and also honors PHP's desired setting of fastcgi.impersonate=1.

Steps 1,2 and 4 are the same - step 3 is different.

1. Ensure each site has its own application pool (same as above)
2. Under Advanced Settings > Processing Model > Application Pool Identity (same as above)
3. IIS > Authentication > Anonymous Authentication > Application Pool Identity (not IUSR)
4. Set read/write permissions using IIS AppPool\MyAppPoolName (same as above)

We do not grant IUSR or IIS_IUSRS access to the webroot.  All permissions are assigned to IIS AppPool\MyAppPoolName